# Generate Resource Designer cs programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I alter the "*Resource.resx*" files in different projects from my application and generate them.

The changes won´t be recognized until I select the"*Resource.resx*" file in Visual Studio and run the custom tool (ResXFileCodeGenerator).

Is there a way to run the custom tool or to generate the "*Resource.Designer.cs*" file **programmatically**?

I tried to make it happen with the "*ResGen.exe*", but it just produces resource files. To generate the"*Resource.resx*" files I use the System.ResourcesResXResourceWriter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done in code:
See this link from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Basically this is the code:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@".\DemoResources.cs");
  string[] errors = null;
  CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
  CodeCompileUnit code = StronglyTypedResourceBuilder.Create("Demo.resx", "DemoResources", 
                                                             "DemoApp", provider, 
                                                             false, out errors);    
  if (errors.Length > 0)
     foreach (var error in errors)
        Console.WriteLine(error); 

  provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(code, sw, new CodeGeneratorOptions());                                         
  sw.Close();
```

Comment: and you need to reference system.design.dll